# Join two tables on two fields

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgresql and trying to join two tables on two fields:

```
SELECT a.high, a.low, a.stname, a.zipcode, b.bhs, b.street_numb, b.street, b.address, b.zipcode
FROM bin a
JOIN zp b
ON (a.stname = b.street) and (a.low = b.street_numb);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 4: on (a.stname = b.street) and (a.low = b.street_numb);
                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How would I be able to get the correct result?

Comment: `You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking Postgres to compare two different types, `character` and `integer`.  If you're sure `a.low` will be numeric,

```
CAST (a.low AS INT) = b.street_numb
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. I decided to alter table, and re-run the query as I had it.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE zp ALTER COLUMN street_numb TYPE character(5);

Comment: After running this alter table code, I refreshed the DB and re-ran originally query (top of page) and it worked perfectly. The problem was that low field was a character and street_numb was a integer. Using alter table i converted street_numb to a character. This allowed the original query to run without error.